# Difference between linux exit 1 vs false command

Tags: linux, shell, rpm, rpm-spec

IN RPM installation i am using false command (in pre section) in case the rpm is already install. Despite executing false command , the rpm installation continues. But when i use "exit 1" , RPM installation fails.

Just want to know why "false" command is unable to stop execution.

Comment: `false` doesn't exit the shell, so I'm not sure why you think it should make installation fail.

Comment: got it.. Thanks@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I believe the `%pre` scriptlet is run with `set -e`, which *does* exit a script on any non-zero command return.

Answer (score 1):

`false` command just sets an exit code of 1 like this

```
$ false
$ echo $?
1
$
```

The script has to decide on what to do with this exit code, e.g. to stop execution with an `exit $?`. (Be careful `$?` always contains the exit code of the last executed command. After `echo $?` it contains the exit code of the `echo` command...)

Most time I use `false` only as a place holder while writing scripts or testing/debugging branches in scripts